# Classes And Objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object, oop

I am new to oops and not understanding **Object's** and **Method's** I have written two methods in **Dog Class** one is **getDogInfo** and other is **anotherDogInfo** the first method is printing correct values and other is printing null why is that, what am i doing wrong in this code ?

```
public class Dog {

    String breed;
    String name;
    int life;
    
    public void getDogInfo() {
        System.out.println("His name: " + name);
        System.out.println("His lifespan: " + life);
        System.out.println("His Breed: " + breed);
    }
    
    public void anotherDogInfo() {
        Dog laila = new Dog();
        laila.name ="laila";
        laila.life = 9;
        laila.breed = "huskey";
        System.out.println("His name: " + name);
        System.out.println("His lifespan: " + life);
        System.out.println("His Breed: " + breed);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dog charlie = new Dog();
        charlie.name = "charlie";
        charlie.breed = "DoberMan";
        charlie.life = 15;
        charlie.getDogInfo();
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        
        Dog laila = new Dog();
        laila.anotherDogInfo();
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: your anotherDogInfo uses a local instance of a Dog, which makes no sense at all, then, you print the name and such of the instance you are in, not of that local instance

Comment: The `laila` in the `main` method and the `laila` in the `anotherDogInfo` method are two different instances. Only the latter has its fields set to non-default values, whereas the former does not. You're printing the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistakes you made:**

1. You have created the object laila two times i.e. one in the main() function and the other is in anotherDogInfo() method.
2. You must create the object inside the main() method.

**Solution**:
Try this code, it is working perfectly.

```
public class Dog {
    String breed;
    String name;
    int life;
    
    public void getDogInfo() {
        System.out.println("His name: " + name);
        System.out.println("His lifespan: " + life);
        System.out.println("His Breed: " + breed);
    }
    
    public void anotherDogInfo() {
       
        System.out.println("His name: " + name);
        System.out.println("His lifespan: " + life);
        System.out.println("His Breed: " + breed);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dog charlie = new Dog();
        charlie.name = "charlie";
        charlie.breed = "DoberMan";
        charlie.life = 15;
        charlie.getDogInfo();
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        
        Dog laila = new Dog();
        laila.name ="laila";
        laila.life = 9;
        laila.breed = "huskey";
        laila.anotherDogInfo();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `anotherDogInfo`, when you do the printing, you're using the values from the current object instead of those from the one you created (`laila`).